# question about pde

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Consider the equation $u_y=u_x^3$.
Show that the only solutions that are differentiable for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ are linear functions $u(x,y)=ax+a^3y+b$ for some constants $a,b$.

By taking partial derivatives, I can show that the determinant of Hessian matrix is identically zero, but it is still not sufficient to show that  the function is linear. I don't know how to proceed.